# Toggle class using js and the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I am currently using

```
$("ul li").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("checked");
         var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
         $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
});
```

to toggle a class on checkboxes. But if I submit the form and then go back on the browser, it shows the box ticked on any checkboxes I had ticked but they no longer have the class. Is there a way to expand the above to check to see if it's checked an apply the class?

The HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="noclass">
     <input type="checkbox" name="name" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on what this script is supposed to do, really. Check if any of my solutions are on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(function(){
     $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
         var self = $(this);

        if(self.attr('checked')) {
            self.addClass('checked');
        }
    });
});

$('input:checkbox').live('change', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

It will fix your problem :)

This will apply class on parent

```
$(function(){
     $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
         var self = $(this);

        if(self.attr('checked')) {
            self.parent().addClass('checked');
        }
    });
});

$('input:checkbox').live('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: This is pretty close, I should have shown my HTML (added above). This works on the `input:checkbox` but not the `li` element if I switch `input:checkbox` to `ul li`, very close though. I need the class applied to the checkbox container.

Answer (score 1):

Restructure the function so that it toggles the class depending on the checkbox state. Then trigger it once to init.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are changing the class only when you click on the checkbox.  Check if you have given a class for the check boxes which are checked.

it should be something like this

```
 #id .checked{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").bind('click launch', function () {
    var bool = $(this).attr('checked');
    $(this).toggleClass("checked", bool);
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', bool);
}).trigger('launch');
```

- I get the boolean first to check if the binded input is `true` or `false`.
- Then I toggle the class depending on if the #id is checked or not
- Then I check all the checkboxes depending on if the #id is checked or not
- I bind this into an event that fires upon click and my made up event called "launch"
- Lastly I trigger my "launch" so this function is executed, making it occur on page load aswell

**EDIT:**
I've made another version which may be what you're looking for

```
$("ul li").bind('click launch', function () {
    var checkboxes = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
    var bool = Boolean(checkboxes.find(':checked').size());

    $(this).toggleClass('checked', bool);
    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox[0].checked);
}).trigger('launch');
```

Basicly I check if any checkbox is checked and I add the class depending on that. I'm not fully sure what you wish the rest to do, so I simply copied it.

Comment: I actually need the class applied to its container, `li`, I added the HTML above.

Comment: These examples applies the `class="checked"` to the `<li>`.